# Disabling previous date, month, year JTAppleCalendar in iOS using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, jtcalendar

I am using this library:
https://github.com/orazz/CalendarPopUp

Let's say I have a date for registration of user and it's 28/9/2017. Now I want to only enable dates between next date, month and year.
Previous dates, month and year should be disabled.

How can I do that?

How do I disable scrolling and selecting of previous date and month?

[image]

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @ iOS calendar view onMyProfile  'JTAppleCalendar', '6.0'

Comment: ok, Do you have a `canSelect` or a `shouldSelect` delegate function? In there you can prevent dates from being selected by returning either `ture` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set minimum and maximum date. You can change any component like Day, month, year.

**Objective c**

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setMonth:3];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[comps setMonth:-3];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];   
[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

---

**Swift**

```
let gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!   
let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate() 
let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

components.month = -3
let minDate: NSDate = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(components,   toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

components.month = 3
let maxDate: NSDate = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

self.datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
self.datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
```

Comment: thank you sand code but my flow is using the 3rd party library : - https://github.com/orazz/CalendarPopUp

Comment: @JayprakashSingh I think you can use start and end date