# how to hide previous date and month in iOS using swift 3?

Tags: github, swift3, calendar, ios10.3, jtcalendar

i am using the helper libaray "WWCalendarTimeSelector"
GitHub link :- https://github.com/weilsonwonder/WWCalendarTimeSelector 
I have a date for registration of user and it's 29/9/2017. Now I want to only enable dates between next date, month and year.

when starting date select and future date select other date disable 
for example starting date :- 29/09/2017  and future date select  02/10/2017 Seeing the date after that, you will be disable... How can I do that ? please help....

```
@IBAction func btnSelectClick(_ sender: Any) {

        let selector = UIStoryboard(name: "WWCalendarTimeSelector", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! WWCalendarTimeSelector
        selector.delegate = self
        selector.optionCurrentDate = singleDate
        selector.optionCurrentDates = Set(multipleDates)
        selector.optionCurrentDateRange.setStartDate(multipleDates.first ?? singleDate)
        selector.optionCurrentDateRange.setEndDate(multipleDates.last ?? singleDate)

        selector.optionStyles.showDateMonth(true)
        selector.optionStyles.showMonth(false)
        selector.optionStyles.showYear(true)
        selector.optionStyles.showTime(false)
        present(selector, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 func WWCalendarTimeSelectorDone(_ selector: WWCalendarTimeSelector, date: Date) {
        print("Selected \n\(date)\n---")
        singleDate = date
        dateLabel.text = date.stringFromFormat("d' 'MMMM' 'yyyy', 'h':'mma")
    }

    func WWCalendarTimeSelectorDone(_ selector: WWCalendarTimeSelector, dates: [Date]) {
        print("Selected Multiple Dates \n\(dates)\n---")
        if let date = dates.first {
            singleDate = date
            dateLabel.text = date.stringFromFormat("d' 'MMMM' 'yyyy', 'h':'mma")
        }
        else {
            dateLabel.text = "No Date Selected"
        }
        multipleDates = dates
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: So what you are saying is you want the dates after the one you select to be greyed out or somehow show that you can't choose  those dates?

Comment: I see you have asked a similar question here -> [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465319/disabling-previous-date-month-year-jtapplecalendar-in-ios-using-swift-3-0) . It looks like you are still looking for a calendar library which can disable dates. Why don't you try the one i created here? -> [JTAppleCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar). I can show you how to set it up. I also have many video tutorials --> [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyh_DVFeH_w&list=PLpqJf39XekqyUG7dxcqGO0JNprryysv9Q). Simply skip the videos you dont need. Any questions just ask.

Comment: did you got the solution?

Comment: Hi,
i am getting this error when i try to set delegate 
Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'WWCalendarTimeSelector *'

any suggestion how to overcome?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `WWCalendarTimeSelectorShouldSelectDate` method for disabling the dates/date range you need. The below example may help you

```
    fileprivate var today: Date = Date()

    func WWCalendarTimeSelectorShouldSelectDate(_ selector: WWCalendarTimeSelector, date: Date) -> Bool{
        let order = NSCalendar.current.compare(today, to: date, toGranularity: .day)
        if order == .orderedDescending{ {
            //Date selection will be disabled for past days
            return false
        } else {
            //Allows to select from today
            return true
        }
    }
```

You can use your own date range in the above example